# AttributeError: 'PermissionOverwrite' object has no attribute 'items' when editing a VoiceChannel

Tags: python, discord.py

This line of code

```py
await channel.edit(user_limit=0, name="|Dormant", overwrites=discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = False))
```

Sourcing from

```py
elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None: # User left a channel
        channel = before.channel
        if len(channel.members) == 0:
            print("debug 3")
            if str(channel.name).startswith("Currently"):
                print("debug 4")
                await channel.edit(user_limit=0, name=":zzz:|Dormant", overwrites=discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = False))
                await asyncio.sleep(600)
                await channel.edit(name="Waiting for game to be played...", roles=None, reason="The voice channel was empty")
                await channel.set_permissions(role=discord.Role.name())
```

Returns

```py
AttributeError: 'PermissionOverwrite' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Sourcing from

```py
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "z:\Programming\Python\Discord Bots\Channel name changer\main.py", line 37, in on_voice_state_update
    await channel.edit(user_limit=0, name="|Dormant", overwrites=discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = False))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 733, in edit
    await self._edit(options, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 289, in _edit
    for target, perm in overwrites.items():
AttributeError: 'PermissionOverwrite' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Why does it return that error, and what in the code needs to be addressed for it to function properly?

Comment: `overwrites` accepts a `dict` of the permission overwrites. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.TextChannel.edit

Comment: What is your goal? When you set the overwrites to not being able to read messages, do you want this to apply to *everyone*? Or just a specific user? You can use the `dict` arguments to do that.

Comment: @EricJin I want it to apply to everyone, but I'm not sure what `dict` to use for that, and the docs made me non the wiser

Comment: Do you want to retain the current overwrites (only change 1), or delete *everything* (including previous overwrites)?

Comment: @EricJin I wan't to completly reset it. All settings for it can be wiped, as they will be changed later in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the overwrite to apply to everyone, you need to use the [`@everyone` role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=default_role#discord.Guild.default_role) for [`set_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=set_permissions#discord.abc.GuildChannel.set_permissions).

```py
await channel.set_permissions(
  ctx.guild.default_role,  # applies it to @everyone of the guild
  overwrite=discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
)
```

Comment: Does `set_permissions()` take `ctx`?

Comment: You can apply that to a channel. It only takes the role/member to modify and what to modify it with.